# Apollo Server and TypeScript: Type 'GraphQLApi' has no properties in common with type 'DataSource<object>'

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm setting up an interface between our NextJS Front and a series of backends.  The interface will convert the various backs' REST or GraphQL APIs into a unitary GraphQL API.  I'm using the library [apollo-datasource-graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-datasource-graphql) to translate a back that offers a GraphQL API into a datasource to use with Apollo Server.  I'm running into a fair number of TypeScript issues.  At present TS complains about my definition of the Apollo data sources

```
index.ts:10:25 - error TS2559: Type 'InterfaceGraphQLApi' has no properties in common with type 'DataSource<object>'.

10   dataSources: () => ({ gqlApi: new InterfaceGraphQLApi() })
                           ~~~~~~

  node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/graphqlOptions.d.ts:31:5
    31     [name: string]: DataSource<TContext>;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from this index signature.
```

here

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  dataSources: () => ({ gqlApi: new InterfaceGraphQLApi() })
});
```

where `InterfaceGraphQLApi` starts thusly

```
import { GraphQLDataSource } from "apollo-datasource-graphql";
export default class InterfaceGraphQLApi extends GraphQLDataSource {
  baseURL = "http://localhost:4545/admin/api";
```

In the source files for `Apollo-datasource-graphql` (node_modules/src/GraphQLDataSource.ts) I see

`export class GraphQLDataSource<TContext = any> {`

So it seems that I could pass some kind of type parameter, which would be the same as `Datasource<object>` I might be OK?  But I'm far out of my TypeScript/Apollo knowledge zone, so I'm wandering lost here.  Any guidance much appreciated!